# Filter items by last received date

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

My report already has a summary for Items. Now I want to filter these items by their Last Received Date. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You want to filter or order by last received date ?

Comment: Is Last Received Date is a column in database?

Comment: yes exactly i would like to filter by last received date (i want to see the summary for items which last RCVD date is between 1-1-2015 to 31-12-2015

Comment: yes Last RCVD Date is a column in database

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this behavior in the Record Selection. Try something like:

```
{table.lastReceivedDate} >= DATE(2015, 1, 1)
AND
{table.lastReceivedDate} <= DATE(2015, 12, 31)
```

This assumes you don't want any records outside of that date range to appear anywhere in the report. If that's not what you wanted, you can instead use a Running Total with the same logic in the suppression section.